# Cakephp SQL error with join and fields

Tags: php, sql, cakephp, join, orm

I'm creating a website and during the development I changed the database system from mysql to postgresql. Everthing seems ok now except when I want to join a table (or several) in the following way (without hasMany, hasOne, etc):

```
$this->find('first', array(
    'joins' => array(
        array(
            'table' => 'table_to_joins', // for instance 'foos'..
            'alias' => 'TableToJoinJoin', // ..which implies 'FooJoin'
            'type' => 'INNER',
            'conditions' => array(
                'TableToJoinJoin.a_field1 = CurrentTable.a_field2'
            )
        )
    ),
    'conditions' => array(...),
    'fields' => array('CurrentTable.*', 'TableToJoinJoin.*')
);
```

I get the error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function schema() on a non-object in .../lib/Cake/Model/Datasource/Database/Postgres.php on line 405
```

The problem is that the non-object is TableToJoinJoin. In Postgres.php the code is:

```
if (!preg_match('/^.+\\(.*\\)/', $fields[$i]) && !preg_match('/\s+AS\s+/', $fields[$i])) {
                if (substr($fields[$i], -1) === '*') {
                    if (strpos($fields[$i], '.') !== false && $fields[$i] != $alias . '.*') {
                        $build = explode('.', $fields[$i]);
                        /* !! build[0] is TableToJoinJoin  !! */ $AssociatedModel = $model->{$build[0]};
                    } else {
                        $AssociatedModel = $model;
                    }

                    /* line 405 */ $_fields = $this->fields($AssociatedModel, $AssociatedModel->alias, array_keys($AssociatedModel->schema()));
                    $result = array_merge($result, $_fields);
                    continue;
                }
...
```

It happens only when I use TableToJoinJoin.*, if I specify each field like TableToJoinJoin.id, TableToJoinJoin.foo, etc, it works. I have many queries like that so if anyone can help, that would be great!

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem. After some trial and error I've found that if I map the relationship (via $belongsTo, $hasMany, etc) in the model, the join will work without errors. Sub-optimal, but that's all I've got.